# Is the MVC-pattern a pure presentation-tier pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

Kind of a special question today :)

I just had a test at my technical university where I was told that I am wrong.

So I like to know from you folks(I believe you more than my teachers):

Is the MVC-pattern implemented at the presentation-layer only?
Or is the Model-part of the pattern in the Business/DataAccess-layer implemented.

My teacher said, it's not possible that a pattern can span more than one tier.
But I think it's an an enterprise-architecture-pattern and therefore can span multiple tiers.

How wrong am I? :)

Comment: your teacher is wrong.  by definition there is no such constraints on a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wrong... for the class. In class, what teacher<del>/book</del> says goes.

Outside class, I agree with you 100%.

Comment: I didn't know the teachers view on things. (guess I skipped to many classes).  They told me only after they interviewed me on the subject. Unfortunately that was too late :)

Comment: accepted this as the solution. though maybe Skliwz is right. but i can't tell what is right, so its difficult to favor an answer.

Comment: What Skliwz says is also true, from a certain point of view (i.e. the POV of the front-end).

Comment: I guess when it comes to education, the customer is not always right.

Answer (score 4):

Your teacher is right, the "model" merely represents data that is to be presented. For example, the data that makes up a web page.

The data itself will ultimately come from the business layer, but the model should be restricted to the presentation layer. It's the model of your presentation.

For example, you might retrieve data as datasets, and use the datasets to build page-specific models.

Comment: Note the final page shaped objects come in the way of ViewModels that might be populated from the Models.

Answer (score 2):

I would think MVC does go deeper than presentation tier for the simple reason that supplying the model does require other tiers to do "something".

Besides if we think of model as some representation of [Domain concepts (see DDD)](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice) - then we are already talking about going outside of Presentation tier.