# Model View Controller - where to keep simple logic

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I often see very different implementations of the Model View Controller Pattern, and completely understand that you should adapt and use what fits your needs the best, but I was wondering what would be the advantages/disadvantages/best practice of keeping simple game logic in ether the controller or model?

In essence which is the correct way I should be doing this?

for this simple example the player receives damage and I have listed three possible ways of dealing with it:

**1.**

*contoller:*

```
_model.playerDamage - 15;
if (_model.playerDamage <= 0){
    _model.playerLives --;
    _model.restartLevel();
}
```

**2.**

*controller:*

```
_model.playerDamage = 15;
```

*model:*

```
function set playerDamage(value:int){
     playerDamage = value;
     updatePlayer();
}

function updatePlayer():void{
    if (playerDamage<=0){
         palyerLives --;
         restartLevel();
    }
}
```

**3.**

*controller:*

```
_model.playerDamage = 15;
_model.addEventListener('playerChange', checkPlayerStatus);

function checkPlayerStatus(e:Event):void{
    if (_model.playerDamage<=0){
         _model.playerLives --;
         _model.restartLevel();
    }
}
```

*model:*

```
function set playerDamage(value:int){
     playerDamage = value;
     dispatchEvent(new Event('playerChange'));
}
```

Comment: ok thanks - would you therefore keep all logic in the model? and just use controllers to set things in the model?

Comment: i'd use model as a data structure api - you can retrieve what you need after you input all it needs - and no one else should know how this values were calculated :) and controller just to pass data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ofcourse in Model because you may have multiple controllers (in future) which affect things in Model in similar or same way. Controllers are just a mechanism to translate UI events into business events. Model is the place that crunches the logic.

You may find following stackoverflow threads useful:

1. [Is the MVC-pattern a pure presentation-tier pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091378/is-the-mvc-pattern-a-pure-presentation-tier-pattern/5091453#5091453)
2. [What do I call the code that orchestrates my web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301888/what-do-i-call-the-code-that-orchestrates-my-web-application/5308249#5308249)

Though they are java specific but the ideas discussed here are platform independent.

Hope that helps.